# Reducing the font size in a table but not throughout the document?

Tags: typography

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!htb]
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                   Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                     }  
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
b     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
            & \sigma  & Progression rate from the asymptomatic compartment to the symptomatic compartment  \\
\mu & Natural death rate 
            & \gamma_A       & Non-treatment recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
\beta_A & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
            & \gamma_I       & Non-treatment recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\beta_I & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & \eta & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\nu       & Vaccination rate of newborns
            & \xi     & Immunity loss rate     \\
\rho       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
            & \alpha       & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Description of paramters}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

How can I reduce the font size to say size 11 in the table while maintaining size 12 "everywhere" else?

Comment: I would use  `\small`  just after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `cells = {font=\fontsize{9}{11}` to the arguments of your tabular:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!htb]
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                   Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt},
                     cells = {font=\fontsize{9}{11}}
                     }  
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
b     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
            & \sigma  & Progression rate from the asymptomatic compartment to the symptomatic compartment  \\
\mu & Natural death rate 
            & \gamma_A       & Non-treatment recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
\beta_A & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
            & \gamma_I       & Non-treatment recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\beta_I & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & \eta & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\nu       & Vaccination rate of newborns
            & \xi     & Immunity loss rate     \\
\rho       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
            & \alpha       & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Description of paramters}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

> You can also use \tiny command see minmal example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Article}
\author{Yan}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
    \tiny % tiny font size
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    
    \hline
      Column 1   & Column 2 \\
    \hline
      Column 3   & Column 4\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```